# Selenium Webdriver Python wont find element to click by xpath despite it existing on page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i have my webdriver looking for this element but it never does

```
//*/a/text()='qe_ta_vcn_ZFI1lK_UpdateListChangeVcn'
```

I can see from XpathHelper tool that the xpath will match 1 element.

The error says

```
File "/home/ovcaqe/ossetest/usr/src/lib/pca/pca_3x/utils/CE/base_ui_util.py", line 210, in wait_for_by_xpath_then_click
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*/a/text()='qe_ta_vcn_rhqYXk_UpdateListChangeVcn' because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

My code

```
Log.info(f"Waiting for {wait_for_seconds}, then clicking element with xpath {element_xpath}")
sleep(wait_for_seconds)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
```

Comment: please post the html also

Comment: You did not post the HTML but perhaps the element can be in an iframe. So, if that is the case, you have to switch to that iframe with selenium, and then ask selenium to search for it.

Comment: Cant post the html due to stackoverflows limitations on how much code you can post but here is the full Xpath to the element (note the name is variable as i'm selecting something in a list).       /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/oj-module/section/div[2]/div/div[3]/oj-table/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a

Comment: a[text()='qe_ta_vcn_ZFI1lK_UpdateListChangeVcn'] try using this.